# How Can I Test My CDK Created, API Gateway Invoked, Lambda With Automated Jest Tests?

Tags: typescript, testing, aws-cdk

**Use Case:**

I have created a variety of endpoints in my API Gateway Stack that invoke Lambda functions as a part of their intergration. When I make changes to the code, I would like to ensure the lambdas work and offer the correct response.

As I am using the `CLI` and `cdk deploy --all`, I would like to use [interface Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_cloud-assembly-schema.Hooks.html) as a part of the pre-deployment.

**API Gateway Code:**

```
this.httpApi = new HttpApi(this, "HttpApi");
this.httpApi.addRoutes({ path: "/example", methods: [HttpMethod.POST], integration: new HttpLambdaIntegration("integration", lambdaStack.exampleLambda });
```

**Lambda Code:**

Note, I pass in the environment variable `STEP_FUNCTION_ARN` via the CDK.

```
export async function handler(event: any, context: object) {
  const stepFunctionParams: { stateMachineArn: string; input: string; name: string; } = {
    stateMachineArn: process.env.STEP_FUNCTION_ARN!,
    input: event.body,
    name: "name" 
  };

  try {
    await client.send(new StartExecutionCommand(stepFunctionParams));
    return { statusCode: 200, body: "Success!"};
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Problem executing SF :", JSON.stringify(e));
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: "Problem executing step function : " + JSON.stringify(e),
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    };
  }
}
```

As someone writing their first suite of tests for these resources, what do I need to do?

Comment: The `Hooks` API you refer to is meant to be used with the [@aws-cdk/integ-tests-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html) module.  Pass the hooks to the [IntegTest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_integ-tests-alpha.IntegTest.html) construct.

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information fedonev!

Comment: Api gw have canary tests you can [run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html)